# Center menu and extend background-color to the width of the wrapper

Tags: html, css, menu

***How would I center these two menus and extend the background-color of each `#wrap` to the full width of the `#wrap`?***

I'm working with the idea that browsers can be told to treat divs as table cells, i.e. `display: table; margin: 0 auto;`.

Is this correct? Is there a better way to center the menu and fill the `#wrap` background color?

**Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kwcp4/1/**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="nav">
<div class="wrap">
<ul class="menu menu-primary">
<li class="menu-item"><a href="http://#">Menu 1 Link 1</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="http://#">Menu 1 Link 2</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="http://#">Menu 1 Link 3</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="http://#">Menu 1 Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="subnav">
<div class="wrap">
<ul class="menu menu-secondary">
<li class="menu-item"><a href="http://#">Menu 2 Link 1&nbsp;</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="http://#">Menu 2 Link 2&nbsp;</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="http://#">Menu 2 Link 3&nbsp;</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="http://#">Menu 2 Link 4&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrap {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu-primary,
#header .menu {
    background-color: #FE9DA6;
    clear: both;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
}

.menu-secondary,
#header .menu {
    background-color: #2EA379;
    clear: both;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
}


.menu-primary,
.menu-secondary {
    padding: 5px; 
}


.menu-primary,
.menu-secondary {
    display: table; margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrap {
    width: auto;display: table;margin: 0 auto;
}  


.menu-primary ul,
.menu-secondary ul,
#header .menu ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu-primary li,
.menu-secondary li,
#header .menu li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-primary a,
.menu-secondary a,
#header .menu a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 8px 6px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header .menu a {
    padding: 8px 15px 7px;
}

#header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i do understand your question, `margin: 0 auto;` is a good way to center **div's**. 
But for the **background color**, isn't it better to use the backgrounds on the **div's**: 
 
`<div id="nav">` and `<div id="subnav">` ?

**Css:**

```
#nav {background-color: #FE9DA6;}
#subnav {background-color: #2EA379;}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kwcp4/3/)**

Comment: Well, that was much simpler than what I was trying, which was too complex. That works. Thanks.